# How to update data from gridview button using C#?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a grid that has "`start_time` and `end_time`" in it. They are used to start and check process status in between these two times.

Now, I want to add a button to the grid and to update these two ( "`start_time` and `end_time`") cells into the Db, so that I need not to support them whenenver they are running.

Comment: Put more light by posting your code, so one can answer it quickly

Comment: My question is very straight.....I want to add a button to the grid and to update these two ( "start_time and end_time")  to the database.

Comment: Where is the updated data, in that same gridview? What exactly is the problem, the sql part; the Button in gridview part? How is that DB connected? Are you using EF, procedures, select statements? What have you tried? Where is your c# attempt? .... ..... .....